# Align a Header and Normal Text in Same Line after image logo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to align the header Orders Management:
and the normal text  Logged in as:  Admin , Logout in the same line.
It works when it is the only one.
[link](http://jsfiddle.net/XPE3w/3058/)

but when I integrate it . It is not align as you can see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5n2h03nL/4/)

```html
<div id="dialog-form" title="Order Details">
  <p class="validateTips">Spicy Sandwitch</p>
  <p class="validateTips">More</p>
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name">More Comments</label>
      <p class="validateTips">Sandwitch only lettuce</p>
      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
<div class="header">
  <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo"  />
  <h1>Cafe name</h1>
</div>
<p style="clear: both;"></p>
  <!--<h1>Orders Management:</h1>-->
  <div style="border-bottom:1px ;"> 
<div class="left"><h1>Orders Management:</h1></div>
<div class="right"><span class="blackText">Logged in as: </span>&nbsp;<span class="blueText">Admin</span>&nbsp;<span class="blackText">,</span>&nbsp;<span class="redText">Logout</span>
 </div>
</div>
<!-- -->
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name/Surname</th>
        <th>Address</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th>Time/Date</th>
        <th>Order Details</th>
        <th>Delivered</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Lykavitou 12, 2109 Aglantzia</td>
        <td>99123456</td>
        <td>21:00 21/11/16</td>
        <td>

          <button id="create-user-1" class="showDialog">Show</button>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" />
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Andreas Georgiou</td>
        <td>Grigori Auxentiou 12, 2109 Aglantzia</td>
        <td>99654789</td>
        <td>20:00 21/11/16</td>
        <td>
          <button id="create-user-2" class="showDialog">Show</button>
        </td>
        <td align="center">
          <input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1" />
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

And I am trying to make the logout text to be a hyperlink that will redirect to an html page in the same folder . The   did not worked.

Comment: remove your header width 300px; use 100% width

Comment: @JishnuVS in css?

Comment: @JishnuVS still didn't worked if you mean in css

Comment: yes check with my answer and remove your browser catch and reload it, this will worked for me

Answer (score 0):

In order to make the Logout and Admin `<div>`s elements appear on one line they need to be contained by containers that do not fill out the width of a line by default (**block** elements like `<div>`, `<p>` tags).

Replace the `div` elements for Admin and Logout with inline elements (e.g. `<span>` will allow you you create content that appears on a line/row together.

A `block` element like a `<div>` will by default both start on a newline *and* fill the width of that line.

It will do this unless it has its display property set to `inline-block` rather than the default `block` but you also have to provide a width to the `div in this case.

Since you have set the display to `inline-block` all you have to do is provide the same `<`div>`s with a width property.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the width of `div#users-contain`. With the width of only 300px, there is only so much space there

[image: With the width of only 300px, there is only so much space there]